# Cannot recover freed disk space after Bootcamp disk recovery

Tags: windows, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

My MacBookPro16,1 was running Windows 10Pro via Bootcamp and after an update I could no longer boot into Windows. So I spent 2 days backing up my data and trying to run Windows recovery tools to no avail. My final option then became to remove bootcamp and reinstall bootcamp/windows.

Windows had been installed via bootcamp on a 4TB NTFS partition. I have MacOS Big Sur 11.7.3 on the Mac.

I went through the Bootcamp utility, as instructed in the Apple support, and ran the “Restore disk to a single macOS partition" option. This did indeed remove Windows 10 and the BOOTCAMP NTFS partition. Now I have 4 TB of free space however I cannot reinstall Windows on this as it does not recognize this 4TB. Bootcamp wants to install on an APFS partition (is this something new? it's been several years since I did the initial Windows 10/bootcamp install and if I recall correctly, it needed to go on an NTFS partition).

Here is what the disk volumes look like now:

```
jami@Jamis-MacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         1.0 TB     disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨MacData_NTFS⁩            3.0 TB     disk0s3
                    (free space)                         4.0 TB     -

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.3 GB    disk1s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.3 GB    disk1s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     626.9 GB   disk1s2
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 437.3 MB   disk1s3
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                623.2 MB   disk1s4
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      20.5 KB    disk1s5
```

And here is what it looks like when I try to install Windows10 with Bootcamp:
[image: Bootcamp Win Install]

What can I do to (re)install windows on a partition the uses the 4TB of free space?

I tried running resizeContainer to add/allocate the 4TB of free space to the APFS partition but that didn't work.

I got an error as follows:

```
 % sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
Password:
Started APFS operation
Error: -69519: The target disk is too small for this operation, or a gap is required in
 your partition map which is missing or too small, which is often caused by an attempt
to grow a partition beyond the beginning of another partition or beyond the end of
partition map usable space
```

Comment: To use the Boot Camp Assistant to reinstall Windows 10, you would first need to delete the volume named ⁨MacData_NTFS⁩. After deleting, you can enter the `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0` command.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson - That volume only holds data and did not have the Bootcamp install on it. I have a back up but do I really need to delete that partition? I just hate the thought of having to restore all that data. Of course if it is the only option, I'll do it. Also does bootcamp now only install on APFS and not NTFS?

Comment: As I already stated, the partition needs to be deleted in order to use the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10. However, you can also choose to not delete the partition and manually install Windows 10. If you choose to manually install, then I would suggest manually installing Windows 11 instead. I believe upgrading is still free. All MacBookPro16,1 processors are supported by the current Window 11 release (Windows 11 version 22H2). I should also point out the Windows 10 retirement date is Oct 14, 2025. Windows installs on NTFS. You can not install Windows on APFS.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you, @DavidAnderson, for the response. Once I deleted the other NTFS partition I ran BootCamp Assistant and reinstalled Windows 10 easily.  Decided to hold off on Windows 11 for now, since I'll probably be upgrading to a new computer by the time they retire Win10. I then used DiskUtility to recreate my NTFS data partition. I use that to store my data that I need to access in both Mac and Windows - I use Paragon software to access the NTFS drive when running MacOS.